# ¿Guardar los datos de una consulta de postgresql en javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy utilizando Nodejs, para la parte de postgresql estoy usando pg-promise.
Con la siguiente función se realiza la consulta, pero quisiera guardar la variable **data** que es la que tiene los valores de la consulta, para poder usarlos después.

```
    function getUnUsuario2(req, res, next) {
  var pupID = req.body.usuario;
  db.any('select * from tienda.usuarioadmin where nombre_usuario= $1', pupID)
    .then(function (data) {
      localStorage.Usuariosa=data;
      if(data[0]==null){
       res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'No existe D:'
        });
```

```
  }
```

else{
res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/admindashboard');
      }

`})


.catch(function (err) {
  return next(err);
});`

}

Comment: A parte de la respuesta, te sugiero que para usar pg-promise antes le eches un vistazo a la documentación y a la demo que tiene: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo

Comment: LocaStorage no esta disponible para NodeJs, solo lo esta para los navegadores, por otra parte no entiendo por que quieres guardar la información que lees, para usarla después, si haces eso tus datos no se mantendrán actualizados con lo que tienes en tu DB, ¿podrías proporcionar una aclaración del por que quieres hacer algo como eso?

Comment: @Uriel  Es por qué debo mostrar los datos que tengo guardados.

Comment: Entonces simplemente responde a la llamada con los datos en res.status(200).json({data: data});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que debes tener claro es que localStorage/sessionStorage solamente están disponible en el navegador (cliente). Debería ser éste quien se encargue de almacenar los datos que necesites en el localStorage. El servidor no puede acceder a dicho almacenamiento.

Existen algunas librerías que pueden ayudarte, aunque personalmente no las he utilizado: 
    https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage

Si pretendes almacenar esos datos en el navegador del cliente, puedes enviar el objeto data en la respuesta del servidor y, una vez en el cliente, que sea tu frontend el que almacena dicho dato en el localStorage.

Comment: Hola @jmpmscorp. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir! Quizás, para completar la respuesta, convendría agregar un ejemplo mínimo de código mostrando cómo utilizarlo.

Comment: Hola @Mariano.. disculpa que no pusiera un ejemplo. Es la primera vez que escribia una respuesta y no sabía que habría que ponerlo. Espero que con las respuestas que le hemos dado sean suficientes. En caso contrario, edito y pongo ejemplo. Gracias por tu bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversos modulos para javascript que permiten realizar conexiones y consultas en bases de datos realacionales como [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/). Donde indican la forma de conectarse a la base de datos, crear modelos dentro del proyecto  para generar los distintos querys y  consultas. Que dentro de la documentacion indican que puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects', { raw: true })
      .then(projects => {
//Aquí manejar  retornar los datos
console.log(projects) //Se muestran los datos por consola
 })
```

De tal forma que puede manejar los datos que necesita para validar el proceso que viene realizando